# A pdf in an iframe is displayed differently depending on browser

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I want to show a pdf document within an iframe, (that's a client request not to leave the page).
This pdf document is a fictional form that has notes in order to explain to user how to fill it later.
You can see it here:

http://www.ideforce.fr/?q=content/processus-dinscription-chsct (click the **“Example”** button)

It works in Firefox (pdf shows up, notes are displayed on hover). In Opera pdf shows up, but I can't show the notes. In Chrome and Safari, the pdf displays ridiculously tiny, but I can zoom it, then the text in the notes misses the apostrophes and accentuated letters disappear (you'll have notice the site is french…)

Does the problem come from the web browser? Below is how I've implemented the iframe.

```
<iframe class="affichage-pdf" src="/sites/default/files/bi_cdt_test.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Or does the problem come from the pdf generated?

I would love to understand what is wrong.

NB:
In Opera I get the notes, but without the accents still.

Comment: Thanks @slee423, though ‘Exemple’ is still in french on th site ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tryout these two codes:

```html
<object class="affichage-pdf" data="/sites/default/files/bi_cdt_test.pdf"></object>

<object data="/sites/default/files/bi_cdt_test.pdf"></object>
```

One of them should be working absolutely fine. Instead of iframe try with object as it is more powerful tag than iframe.

Comment: Great! You advice on using <object> instead of <iframe> solves my problem of zooming. I still cannot figure out how to print the extra characters.